# Using Angular pipes to set css class

Tags: angular, angular-pipe, angular10

I have an angular material autocomplete that allows users to select multiple options. The options that user selected must appear in red color to indicate that they were already selected. If the user selects them again, the option gets unselected. I know that using a class method in template is not good for the performance, so I created a pipe to achieve that. However, the pipe only receives the values in the dropdown when the component loads.

How can I resolve this?

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Advisor Name/Port ID" aria-label="advisor-autocomplete" matInput
    [formControl]="advisorName" [matAutocomplete]="advisorAC"/>

  <mat-autocomplete #advisorAC="matAutocomplete"
    (optionSelected)="optionSelected($event)">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let advisor of filteredAdvisors | async" [value]="advisor.advisorPortId">
      <span
        [ngClass]="{'option--selected': advisor.advisorPortId | isSelected:selectedAdvisors}">{{ advisor.advisorFullName + ' (' + advisor.advisorPortId + ')' }}</span>
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

**selectedAdvisors** is an array that stores the selected options

```
@Pipe({
      name: 'isSelected',
    })
    export class IsSelectedPipe implements PipeTransform {
      transform(value: string, selectedValues: string[]): boolean {
        console.log(value);
        console.log(selectedValues);
    
        return selectedValues.includes(value);
      }
    }
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Have you tried moving them to round braces? (advisor.advisorPortId | isSelected:selectedAdvisors)

Comment: Also pipe are for formatting data for display, not sure if the object passed to ngClass will be checked for any pipes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'isSelected',
    pure: false // this is the key
})
```

Comment: is my approach correct? Can I use pipe to achieve what I am trying to achieve? is it recommended?

Comment: Well, it`s a "use at your own risk" case. Its definitely not recommended for some heavy logic. But with simple one your are going to be fine.